# How to capture BadHttpRequestException in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

### Summary

I'm struggling to find a way to capture low-level HTTP exceptions thrown by Kestrel in an ASP.NET Core application. I can see minimal information about them in the console (`BadHttpRequestException: Malformed request: invalid headers`) but ideally I'd like to be able to place a breakpoint somewhere so I can analyse these requests in detail.

### Background

I'm trying to create a LabVIEW application that communicates with an ASP.NET Core-based webservice I wrote. LabVIEW itself doesn't directly support websocket communication, and a library I discovered to add support for this isn't working correctly so I'm trying to manually construct the TCP message I need to send to perform the upgrade.

If I try to open a websocket connection to my webservice using, for example, Firefox's Simple WebSocket Client extension, then the connection succeeds and I can communicate with my webservice through it just fine. I can also use Firefox's dev tools to inspect the HTTP upgrade request. However, if I try to send a similarly-constructed message from LabVIEW using its TCP library, the connection fails and I see a `BadHttpRequestException` appear in my webservice's console complaining about invalid headers.

### What I've Tried

My first approach was to try adding middleware to capture the requests being made from LabVIEW. In my `Startup` class, I added the following very basic middleware so I could essentially break on requests the moment they enter the pipeline:

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
    await next();
});
```

This was placed above all other configured middleware. Unfortunately, control flow never reached this point when sending requests from LabVIEW, and I assume this is because the middleware pipeline won't get triggered if a low-level exception like `BadHttpRequestException` gets thrown.

My second attempt was using Fiddler. This didn't help either, as it wasn't showing any traffic coming from LabVIEW.

This is the LabVIEW code I'm using to perform the initial handshake:

[image]

This code attempts to open a connection to localhost on port 36364 (which succeeds) and then send the specified HTTP GET request over it, ensuring that CRLF is used for all line endings.

Comment: Plase make sure that your `\n` -> `\r\n` replacement does not do `\r\n` -> `\r\r\n`, as that might make the headers incorrect. Also, here is a Q&A which might help you to use Labview with Fiddler (or any proxy for that matter): https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/http-through-proxy-connection/td-p/995656

Comment: @PeterB That looks useful, thanks. I'm not too familiar with this sort of stuff, but Fiddler is configured to "Use System Proxy" under Options > Gateway, and I believe my system proxy is 127.0.0.1:8888 (https://puu.sh/xgrfx/1231ccc9c0.png). Does this mean I should try opening a TCP socket to localhost:8888 and change my GET request to `GET localhost:36364/ HTTP/1.1`? I've tried that but nothing shows up in Fiddler, and my web service doesn't receive anything.

Comment: Fiddler itself is a proxy, and it can talk to yet another proxy downstream if that is what your LAN needs. The point is to make LabView use Fiddler (for that see the link), and then Fiddler will do what it does using whatever system proxy might be needed.

Comment: @PeterB Ah, I see. The proxy at localhost:8888 is Fiddler itself. If I send a GET request using LabVIEW's HTTP library to localhost:8888, I can see it show up in Fiddler. However, my TCP traffic doesn't. I've only recently installed Fiddler and I've just realised that Fiddler probably doesn't support intercepting raw TCP traffic, which might be why I'm not seeing anything. I might need to learn to use Wireshark for this.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you want to capture "BadHttpRequestException". I think all exception including BadHttpRequestException should be handled in the same way in a web application which means we can use IApplicationBuilder.UseExceptionHandler() to capture all the unhanded exceptions. Try this link https://www.strathweb.com/2018/07/centralized-exception-handling-and-request-validation-in-asp-net-core/ it shows how to capture and deal with it. Hope this helps!